# Inner Class Issue

Tags: python, class, object

```
class Canvas:

   def __init__(self):
      sprite_names = []


   class Sprite:
       
      def __init__(self , name):
         
         self.name = name 
         Canvas.sprite_names.append(self.name)
```

So I have a canvas and for each canvas sprites can be instanciated throught them but how can I make so that each canvas has a list with all names of their sprites (What I did here doesn't work).

I thought that by accessing the Canvas class it would work but apparenlty not.

EDIT : I think I found  the solutions (if it's the proper way of doing it then i'l close the question)

```
class Canvas:

   def __init__(self):
      self.sprite_names = []
      


class Sprite:
       
  def __init__(self , canvas_object , name):
         
      self.name = name 
      canvas_object.sprite_names.append(name)

canvas = Canvas()
Sprite = Sprite(canvas , "sprite")

print(canvas.sprite_names)
```

Comment: Python doesn't assign any significance to nested classes. It might make more sense for you to write non-nested classes, and then write methods that allow the classes to interact (e.g. an `add_sprite` method in `Canvas`, or something similar). None of that is going to happen automatically, no matter how you organize the nesting.

Comment: Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: why do you think that `Canvas.sprite_names` should exist? It is an instance method. `Canvas` is the *class*, not an instance. Why are these classes nested to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 
because for each Canvas I instance I should be able to instance sprites that are associated to the canvas I want them to be rendered on.

Comment: @menimeni there is no such association. You certainly don't show any code which makes any such association, and anyway, that doesn't explain why you think `Canvas.sprite_names` should exist, since nowhere are you using any instance of `Canvas`, and are trying to use the classs itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of nested class usage (if that is a requirement) with your sample case study.

```
class Canvas:

   def __init__(self):
      self.sprites = []

   def add_sprite(self, sprite_name):
      new_sprite = self.Sprite(sprite_name)
      self.sprites.append(new_sprite)

   def remove_sprite(self, sprite_name):
      for sprite in self.sprites:
          if sprite.name == sprite_name:
              self.sprites.remove(sprite)
              return
      print('Sprite not found')

   def get_sprite_names(self):
      print([sprite.name for sprite in self.sprites])

   class Sprite:       
      def __init__(self , sprite_name):
         self.name = sprite_name


canvas = Canvas()
canvas.add_sprite('spr1')
canvas.add_sprite('spr4')
canvas.add_sprite('spr7')
canvas.get_sprite_names()
canvas.remove_sprite('spr4')
canvas.remove_sprite('spr2')
canvas.get_sprite_names()
```

Output:

```
['spr1', 'spr4', 'spr7']
Sprite not found
['spr1', 'spr7']
```

Comment: Probably important to note, this class is accessible *anywhere*. That criteria implies that it isn't.

Comment: Even if the nested class *isn't* complex or used anywhere else, it should probably just be defined globally.

Comment: I don't need to test it there. It is just true, btw, that you can access that class *anywhere*, Python doesn't have access modifiers, and your answer implies that this class is somehow hidden. Furthermore, "and deal with them only if you craft methods of the upper-class to interact with it" isn't true either. You don't need to deal with them through methods defined on the outer class. Although, that would probably be a good design. But it isn't *necessary*.

Comment: @chepner for some reasons python designers decided to implement nested classes in their language, yet you seem to be very knowledgeable for what concerns Python, can you go deeper with the reasons behind this choice against nested classes a-priori?

Comment: @lemon they didn't really implement anything, they simply didn't prohibt you from writing a class definition statement inside of another one, nor did they prohibit you from assigning a class as an attribute of another class (which is what a nested class definition results in). But just because it isn't prohibited doesn't mean there is a good reason to do it. Some libraries have chosen to use this (django, pydantic a little bit) both of which involve pretty heavy metaclass magic to make things work well